# Include selected date also in date range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am queering a data in a date range in `MySQL`. When I select the date range
`BETWEEN '2013-01-19 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-21 00:00:00'` the data is shown only 19 and 20 date but not the 21. 
When I write 22 over 21 then data shown from 19-21 not include 22. Now how should I write a query to include the selected date also in date range.

```
Eg: BETWEEN '2013-01-19 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-21 00:00:00' 
Show the data from 19,20,21 Jan 2013.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it includes `2013-01-21` if and only if the recorded date and time is `2013-01-21 00:00:00`. the exclusive date starts on `2013-01-21 00:00:01` and up

so to solve your problem, use `23:59:59` to include the whole time of the selected day.

```
BETWEEN '2013-01-19 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-21 23:59:59'
```

Comment: you're welcome `:D`. btw, using `DATE()` function kills the index if you have define one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select data based only on the date, use the function `DATE()` to extract the date part of the data.  I.e.

```
DATE(fieldname) BETWEEN '2013-01-19' AND '2013-01-21'
```